# Cannot create controller binding since changing to router v2

Tags: ember.js

Have just upgraded my application to 1.0.0-pre.4 and am in the process of changing my router to the new router API, however I cannot seem to be able to create a binding between my controllers anymore.

So in my main ApplicationController, I have the following:

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    user: App.User.create()
});
```

And then in v1 of the router API, I had the following:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    userBinding: 'App.router.applicationController.user',
});
```

However, with changing over to v1 of the router API, App.router is no longer defined. Everything I try does not seem to work, even setting userBinding to 'App.ApplicationController.user' does not work - it's as if the applicationController no longer is working.

What I am trying to achieve is to create an instance of my user model and then share it across a number of routes/views.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be useful to read this: https://gist.github.com/4639391 and watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ed_o3_59ME (Note that the router syntax has changed since that video but it's still informative) to update your mental model of what's going on in Ember 1.0.0-pre.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Ember have hidden all instances of the singleton controllers to prevent users from implementing bad practice code. You shouldn't be referencing controllers explicitly, and instead you should be decoupling everything and using dependency injection to pass in *things* to your controller.

In the previous releases of Ember, we had `connectControllers` which allowed you to connect controllers to one another, but now with this latest release of Ember, we just use "set" in the router to pass in other controllers.

In your example you have a an `IndexController` and a `UserController`, to get access to the `userController` from within the `indexController`, you'll need to do something like the following:

(Bear in mind that all of this takes place in Ember's Router, which you can read more about here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/)

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    this.controllerFor('index').set('userController', controller);
  }
});
```

Your `indexController` will now have the ability to read information from the `userController`. In a template this may look like the following:

```
{{controller.userController.name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another workaround using "needs" in ObjectControllers.
Here is a reference on how to use this.
http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/04/ember-pre-1-upgrade-notes.html